# Spring OAuth2 Retrieve Authorization Code Grant

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I'm working with a 3rd party REST service that requires retrieving a `authorization code grant` before issuing an access token. The code will be passed along with the client id and secret in order to retrieve that token. In order to get the code, you have to type the username and password in the form and click the `allow` button in order for the code to be generated in the redirect uri.

I don't think it's possible, but can this be done with Spring/Java purely using code and not having to go to the browser to retrieve the code?

Comment: I don't really understand your scenario. Are you writting a client software that should have access to your own data at the 3rd party service? So that in OAuth terminology you are ressource owner and client? Or in other words: Is the username/password that needs to be typed in the web form your own?

Comment: After countless hours digging around, I have a better idea of what's going on. They are using the authorization code grant which I was hoping there was a way to retrieve the code with Java rather than visiting in the browser to authorize the app. Once that's done, i can take that code and get a token that I can use moving forward and not have to worry about generating an authorization code again.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd party REST service needs to provide this functionality (and likely guidance in their API docs). If they do provide it....then yes you can do it entirely in your java code.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand this, it will only be possible to do it with the java code if the REST service provides a mechanism for it, is that right?